# Sublime, Find and Replace with varying numbers

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I'm trying to find and replace all instances of:

```
font-size: pem(18)
```

But the problem is that they all differ in numbers. I'm not a regex expert, i've researched a few ways to do this with no luck as I don't really know what I am looking for to solve this issue.

I know the regex feature exists in Sublime, but when I think of Regex I'm thinking with a javascript or jquery mindset, not pure regex since I'm inexperienced there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simple if you start to learn RegEx:

```
font-size: pem\(\d+?\)
```

First, escape all RegEx metacharacters if you're trying to match that exact character. In this case they are "(" and ")". `\d+` matches one or more digits, ie. 4, 14, 144, etc. If you wanted to get more advanced and limit your integer value to, say, anything between 1 and 19, you could modify the RegEx to:

```
font-size: pem\((?:[1-9]|1[0-9])\)
```

Here, `|` is a standard "or" operator. `\d` is simply shorthand for `[0-9]`, but I've used `[0-9]` here for better readability. `(?: ... )` indicates a non-capturing group so that the closing ")" matches the single "1-9" value as well.

---

Now if you were after changing all integer values you could do a find and replace like so:

Find

```
(?<=font-size: pem\()(?:[1-9]|1[0-9])(?=\))
```

Replace

```
12
```

Then all pem values between 1 and 19 would become 12.